# Discord bot image alignment

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am making a Discord bot for fun and I have no clue what I am doing, but I am trying to make a social command. I got it to work, but the image pushes to the [right](https://freeimage.host/i/XPbcSp) and is not aligned with the link. What could I do to fix this?

```html
const Discord = require("discord.js")
exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setThumbnail("https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/hd-youtube-logo-png-transparent-background-20.png")
  .setDescription('[Click here!](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360038398572-Hyperlink-Markdown)')
  .setColor("#8a5b53")
  message.channel.send({embeds:[embed]})
}
module.exports.name = "socials"
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

So you are creating an embed and using a thumbnail for the image. Thumbnails automatically push to the top right.

Try using `.setImage` which will just put the image inside of the embed normally.

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js")
exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setImage("https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/hd-youtube-logo-png-transparent-background-20.png")
  .setDescription('[Click here!](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360038398572-Hyperlink-Markdown)')
  .setColor("#8a5b53")
  message.channel.send({embeds:[embed]})
}
module.exports.name = "socials"
```

Also check out the [embed guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#embed-preview).